# Making a textbox adjust to the width of the text

Tags: html, css, forms, text

Is it possible, only with CSS to make an input-text expand or shrink to the width of the text?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I use this for live editing for text in an element so it works as a preview for the size of the element containing the text

Comment: Then the natural approach is to use a `span` element with the `contenteditable` attribute. This avoids any specialties in rendering that `input` elements may have as different from normal elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be possible with only CSS, you need to use some jQuery for this as -

```
function resizeInput() {
    $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length+1);
}  

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(resizeInput).each(resizeInput);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GtD7Y/1/)

Comment: thanx, why do you use `each`?

Comment: @IlyaD each is used to initiate the function onload... you can remove each and see the effect :)

Comment: What happens when you paste text into the field?